# Avoid mocking underlying method calls for Mock Objects in Junit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

Below is my code. RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp is from where I get RestTemplate object.
In other class RestTemplateExampleClass which I am testing. I use it as below and it works fine. I have written JUnit to RestTemplate call and it work fine, too.
But when I comment  the below code in my JUnit Test class as restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate()=NULL I get NullPointerException. How can I avoid this? Suppose I had made calls to 10 different classe methods in RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp then i will have to do the same for them too. So how can I avoid it?

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp {
    
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    
    return new RestTemplate();
}


    

given(restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate()).willReturn(restTemplate);
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);






@Autowired
    private RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp restTemplateFactoryForMyApp;
    
restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate().exchange
```

Below is my JUnit testing restTemplate call

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RestTemplateExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp restTemplateFactoryForMyApp;

    @InjectMocks
    private RestTemplateExample restTemplateExample ;
    
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);

    
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        given(restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate()).willReturn(restTemplate);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(restTemplateExample, "id", 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void mock_resttemplate() {
        TodosObject todosObject = new TodosObject();
        todosObject.setId(1);
        
        
        System.out.println(" restTemplateFactoryForMyApp "  + restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate());
        
        int i = (int) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(restTemplateExample, "id");
        
        System.out.println( " value of i " + i);
        
        Mockito
          .when(restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate().exchange(
                "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + i,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                TodosObject.class
        ))
          .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<TodosObject>(todosObject, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not complete sure about your question but maybe [RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) helps:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class RestTemplateExampleTest {

    @Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) 
    private RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp restTemplateFactoryForMyApp;

    @InjectMocks
    private RestTemplateExample restTemplateExample;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(restTemplateExample, "id", 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void mock_resttemplate() {
        TodosObject todosObject = new TodosObject();
        todosObject.setId(1);
        
        
        System.out.println(" restTemplateFactoryForMyApp "  + restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate());
        
        int i = (int) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(restTemplateExample, "id");
        
        System.out.println( " value of i " + i);
        
        Mockito
          .when(restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate().exchange(
                "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + i,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                TodosObject.class
        ))
          .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<TodosObject>(todosObject, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: My question is do i need to mock  just `RestTemplateFactoryForMyApp`  or also mock  `restTemplateFactoryForMyApp.restTemplate()`

Comment: It depends on what you want to test. Unfortunately the test in your question is not complete. In general I think you have to mock the method `restTemplate()`.